Partial specialization of a class for a nested class of a template class
I want to partially specialize a class for a class nested inside a template class, like this
template <typename T, typename U = void>
struct base {
  void print() {
    std::cout << "base specialization" << std::endl;
  }
};

template <typename A, typename B>
struct Outer {
  struct Inner {
    A a;
    B b;
  };
};

// What I am trying to achieve
template< params... >
struct base < specialization ... > {
  void print() {
    std::cout << "Outer::Inner specialization" << std::endl;
  }
};

such that its true for all A, B combination of typenames
I would like to achieve
base<Outer<int, char>::Inner>().print();
base<Outer<char, char>::Inner>().print();
base<Outer<int, float>::Inner>().print();

print Outer::Inner specialization

So the specialisation should be just for the cases when T in base<T> is an instance of Outer<A, B>::Inner?

@Jan Sorry for the int::char, I meant base<Outer<int, char>::Inner>().print(); So If I need to capture these, I would need to explicitly speialize

@Yksisarvinen Yes, for all A,B the specialization should hold

You cannot specialize for Outer<A, B>::Inner directly, but you can specialize for Outer<A, B>.
template <typename A, typename B>
struct base <Outer<A, B>> {
  void print() {
    std::cout << "Outer::Inner specialization" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main() {
    base<Outer<int, char>>().print(); // prints "Outer::Inner specialization"
}

It is not possible to deduce int and char from Outer<int, char>::Inner because ::Inner is a non-deduced context (see What is a non-deduced context?, first heading), but you can deduce them from Outer<int, char>.
Workaround
To access that outer type, you could add some helpful aliases:
template <typename A, typename B>
struct Outer {
  using a_type = A;
  using b_type = B;
  struct Inner {
    using outer_type = Outer;
    A a;
    B b;
  };
};

Then, the partial specialization can be defined as follows:
template <typename>
using void_t = void;

template <typename T>
struct base <T, void_t<typename T::outer_type>> {
  void print() {
    using A = typename T::outer_type::a_type;
    std::cout << "Outer::Inner specialization" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main() {
    base<Outer<int, char>::Inner>().print(); // prints "Outer::Inner specialization"
}

Note that this isn't specializing for any ::Inner per-se; it's specializing for any type that has an outer_type alias member.
See also How do we use void_t for SFINAE?

Yes, I could deduce Outer<A, B>, but I doubted that my requirement won't be possible, thanks for pointing to the correct documentation as to why. The thing is I am getting objects of Outer<A,B>::Inner type, so needed to capture them is a specialization.

@SWARUPSENGUPTA I've updated the answer. The workaround is as close as it gets to what you're trying to do. You will need to make some changes to Inner at least.

that worked, nice way to use void_t for this scenario
